# Group by multiple values

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

For example, I have a list of students with their semesters and subjects.

```
Subject   Semester   Attendee
---------------------------------
ITB001    1          John
ITB001    1          Bob
ITB001    1          Mickey
ITB001    2          Jenny
ITB001    2          James
MKB114    1          John
MKB114    1          Erica
```

When I need to group them by one value with `Stream api`, I can make something like that;

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studlistGrouped =
    studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getSubject()));
```

and it does work. However, when I want to group them by two or more values (like the Sql handles), I cannot figure out how I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to group by a class that holds all the fields you want to group by. This class must implement `hashCode` and `equals` using *all* these fields in order to work as expected.

In your example this would be:

```
public class SubjectAndSemester {

    private final String subject;

    private final int semester; // an enum sounds better

    public SubjectAndSemester(String subject, int semester) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    // TODO getters and setters, hashCode and equals using both fields
}
```

Then, you should create this method in your `Student` class:

```
public SubjectAndSemester bySubjectAndSemester() {
    return new SubjectAndSemester(subject, semester);
}
```

Now, you can group as follows:

```
Map<SubjectAndSemester, List<Student>> studlistGrouped = studlist.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::bySubjectAndSemester));
```

This creates a one level grouping of students.

---

There's another option that doesn't require you to use a `Tuple` or to create a new class to group by. I mean you can have an *n*-level grouping of students, by using downstream `groupingBy` collectors:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Student>>> studlistGrouped = studlist.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSubject,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSemester)));
```

This creates a 2-level grouping, so the returned structure is now a map of maps of lists. If you can live with this, even for grouping of more levels, then you can avoid creating a class that acts as the key of the map.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer looks good but my problem is that I have simplified my example here. Based on the user selection, I should not group by or should group by up to 8 variables. In your first solution, I should create thousands of different combinations for each possibility.

Comment: @drJava Not necessarily... You could create a class with those 8 fields you need to group by in your most fine-grained scenario. Then, if the user hasn't selected 8 fields to group by, just set the non-selected fields to `null` and make `hashCode` and `equals` behave as if those null fields didn't exist, i.e. `hashCode` for a null field should be 0. And for `equals` just compare to `null`. Eclipse and IntelliJ do this automatically for you.

Comment: That means, I need to create only one method like bySubjectAndSemester in your example and the fields, which should not be grouped by, should be set null and the rest is like you have written in your comment?

Comment: @drJava Yes, just be sure to implement `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: I will try now and give you a feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are great. It works like a charm :)

Comment: A last question. Where should I set "non-selected" as null? I mean i should do it in stream or in the list? I mean if i do it in the list, I lose my valuable data.

Comment: @drJava I think you should set non-selected fields to null when creating the class that will be the key of the map.

Comment: Ok, I do it. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated field that is combination of the two columns

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studlistGrouped =
    studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getSubject() + "-" w.getAttendee()));
```

**EDIT:**
Another more "appropriate" solution: Accoridng to [this blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) , you need to define a `Tuple` class that can hold the two columns:

```
class Tuple {
    String subject;
    String attendee;
}
Map<String, List<Student>> studlistGrouped =
    studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> new Tuple(w.getSubject(), w.getAttendee())));
```

Comment: I will try it now and give a feedback for it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Here, in the example I have simplified my example. The actual implementation will be like that; based on the user entry, it may not be groupped by or until 8 fields, it can be groupped. I think also that this example with the tuple may be more appropriate for my case.

Comment: "able to search" is also a talent ;)

Comment: Using string concatenation can lead to ambiguous keys. Further, it’s inefficient. Wrapping that string into a `Tuple` is completely missing the point. Of course, you should create a tuple of the two objects instead: `new Tuple(w.getSubject(), w.getAttendee())`. But note that you don’t need a 3rd party `Tuple` class to achieve this, you can also use `Arrays.asList(w.getSubject(), w.getAttendee())` as `List`s have appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Comment: @Holger, but what if the columns are not of the same type? in this case, the list will have to be `List<Object> ` which might lead to errors when comparing items and so on

Comment: The list doesn’t care about the actual types, so e.g. `map.get(Arrays.asList(oneObject, anotherObject))` will do the right thing. Note that `Tuple` keys won’t be checked any better, as the method’s signature is `Map.get(Object)`. Everything else depends on the intended subsequent processing, for the grouping operation it’s irrelevant. Still, you should fix your `Tuple` example. It doesn’t make sense to show a `Tuple` class having two strings and a use case constructing a `Tuple` with only one concatenated string.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the answer is completely broken: since Tuple doesn't define equals() and hashCode(), two Tuple instances containing the same values are different, and that will thus not group things correctly.